# In each case, find $\overrightarrow {PQ}$ and $\overrightarrow{||PQ||}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

In each case, find $\overrightarrow {PQ}$ and $\overrightarrow{||PQ||}$

P(1,0,1), Q(1,0,-3)

My question is what formula would i use to find $\overrightarrow{||PQ||}$? For $\overrightarrow {PQ}$ would i simply just multiply P and Q to get $\overrightarrow {PQ}$ = (1, 0, -3)? And what is the difference between $\overrightarrow {PQ}$ and $\overrightarrow{||PQ||}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Notice, you should subtract $P(1, 0, 1)$ from $Q(1, 0, -3)$ to find $\vec{PQ}$ as follows $$\vec{PQ}=(1, 0, -3)-(1, 0, 1)$$$$=(0, 0, -4)$$

Comment: Shoudn't it be P-Q?

Comment: No, not really. because $\vec{PQ}$ is directed  from $P$ (tail point) to $Q$ (head point) hence always subtract tail point from head point to find a vector.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the notation.  $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ is the vector FROM point P to point Q.  It does NOT indicate any kind of multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Given two points $P$ and $Q$ the vector $\vec{PQ}$ is defined as $\vec{PQ}=\vec Q -\vec P$ where $\vec P$ and $\vec Q$ are the vectors pointing to the points (note that $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{QP}$ are opposite vectors) .

So, in your case, we have:
$$
\vec{PQ}=(1,0,-3)^T-(1,0,1)^T=(0,0,-4)^T
$$
and $||\vec{PQ}||$ is the modulus of the vector that  (in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$) is defined as:
$$
||\vec{PQ}||=\sqrt{x_{PQ}^2+y_{PQ}^2+z_{PQ}^2}=\sqrt{(-4)^2}=4
$$